# error: operands to ?: have different types 'int' and 'std::basic_ostream<char>'

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int a , b , c , D ;
    double  x1 , x2 ;
    cout << " a = " ;
    cin >> a;
    cout << " b = " ;
    cin >> b;
    cout << " c = " ;
    cin >>c;
    D = pow(b,2) - 4 * a * c;

    x1 = (-b + D ) / (2*a);
    x2 = (- b - D) / (2*a);

    cout << "D = " << D << endl;
    D >= 0 ? ( x1,x2) : (cout << "nope . \n" , x1 = x2 = 0);

    cout << x1 << endl;
    cout << x2 << endl;


    (D % 2) == 1 ? (D++) : (cout << "Number is even . \n" );    //check if number is uneven and if it is then add 1

    cout << D << endl;



 return 0;
}
```

it throws the error :operands to ?: have different types 'int' and 'std::basic_ostream' .
  At the line where is the comment.
Is it possible to fix it by using the conditional operator (?) ?

Comment: Casting both operands to void?

Comment: Stop abusing the conditional operator. Use `if`, it's good.

Comment: `(D % 2) == 1 ? (D++) : (cout << "Number is even . \n" );` - don't write code like that, please. Just write out readable `if` `else` statements.

Comment: well the task wants me to do it with conditional operator

Comment: @Skyline The problem is that the expression has a  value (even if you don't use it) but the two possible branches don't agree on what type that value should be. Edit : Maybe try `(D % 2) == 1 ? (++D) : (cout << "Number is even . \n", D );` so that the expression's value is always the value of `D`.

Comment: @Skyline Then "the task" is *crap*.

Comment: @JesperJuhl unfortunately i just realised... im just a newbie experimenting around

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It worked too ! thank you :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested in comments, cast both operands to `void`:

```
(D % 2) == 1 ? void(D++) : void(cout << "Number is even . \n" );
```

Or even better, use a regular `if`:

```
if (D % 2 == 1)
    D++;
else
    cout << "Number is even . \n";
```

---

You need to do the same thing for the other use of the `? :` as well.

Comment: @Skyline If you figured it out, press the green tick on the left to mark your problem as solved.

Answer (score 2):

It has been said in the comments of the question already but to clarify on this.

The ternary(?) operator has a return type equal to the type of both code branches if the branches do not return the same type then this error will get shown by the compiler.

A comment use of the ternary operator is to assign a value to a variable depending on a condition:

```cpp
bool isConnected = true;
static int idCount = 0;
int connectionID = isConnected ? ++idCount : -1;
```

Comment: so basicially both expression have to be the same type, if not the compiler instantly shows an error ?

Comment: Yes basically. That is why the answers given that use a cast to void work. As then both paths will return void.